# GTK not rendering all user interfaces

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am using gtk+ with c . I have created menu bar and now want to attach a table with some buttons. I have written all essential API routines but, problem I am facing is, if I first create menu bar then table is not rendered to window and it I render table first menu bar is not seen at its place.. .I don't know why. here is the code

```
    /* Button Boxes
 *
 * The Button Box widgets are used to arrange buttons with padding.
 */
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


 GtkWidget *window,*button,*container,*menubar,*fileM,*menu,*vbox,*aboutM,*quitM,*bdrM;
 GtkWidget *image,*table,*Fileframe,*framecnt;
bool status=false;

void aboutDialog()
{
    GtkWidget *box;
    box=gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,GTK_BUTTONS_OK,"EXAMPLE");;
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(box));
    gtk_widget_destroy(box);

}

void Warning_quit()
{
    GtkWidget *box;
    box=gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,GTK_MESSAGE_WARNING,GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO,"Sure want to quit..");
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(box));
    gtk_widget_destroy(box);
    gtk_main_quit();

}

void toggle_Border()
{
    if(status==false)
    {
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window),true);
        gtk_menu_item_set_label(GTK_MENU_ITEM(bdrM),"fix");
        status=true;
    }
    else if(status==true)
    {
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window),false);
        gtk_menu_item_set_label(GTK_MENU_ITEM(bdrM),"move");
        status=false;

    }

}
void initDecoration()
{
    vbox=gtk_vbox_new(false,0);
    menubar=gtk_menu_bar_new();
    fileM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("file");
    aboutM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("about");
    quitM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("quit");
    bdrM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("move");
    menu=gtk_menu_new();
    ////////////////////////
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vbox);//attach vbox with window..
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar),fileM);//attach menu into menubar
    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(fileM),menu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu),aboutM);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar),bdrM);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu),quitM);//attach quit menu with menu..
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),menubar,0,0,1);//attach menubar with vbox//

    //attach signal intrrupt for menus..
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(aboutM),"activate",G_CALLBACK(aboutDialog),0);//signal for about menu..
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quitM),"activate",G_CALLBACK(Warning_quit),0);//signal for quit menu..
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(bdrM),"activate",G_CALLBACK(toggle_Border),0);
}

void initTable()
{
    GtkWidget *button;
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),table); //table attached to main window..
    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("button");
    table=gtk_table_new(4,4,true); //table created..
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table),button,0,1,0,1); //attaching frame container to table cell..

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 200);
  //setup menubar;
  initDecoration();
  initTable();
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),"destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),0);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A function taking no arguments is `(void)` in C, an empty pair of parentheses is not a recommended thing to use.

Comment: have you run my code..

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj i'm runnig it. Had to define true, false and bool otherwise it wouldn't compile. What you expect to achieve?

Comment: See what I am facing is that (1)initTable() is used to put table in window and (2)initDecoration() function is used here to put on the menu bar.. but I call (1)  before (2) I only see table and in vice versa I only see menu bar. Here I want to see both .

Comment: Please learn more about the basics of how containers work, specifically single- versus multi-child containers. `GtkWindow` is not a multi-child container, but here you are trying to add more than one child to it.

Comment: Rolled back to a previous revision. Please avoid changing your question such that existing answers are made useless. If you have a different question, ask a different question.

Comment: I have been restricted to ask further...I dont know what to do know??i am stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add more than one child to the same container, GtkWindow, which only can hold one child.

You did create a vbox but after you did not add the GtkTable, which by the way its deprecated since Gtk+ 3.4, to the GtkBox.

Also note that you are adding the GtkTable to the window before creation and GtkWindow will complain about that.

So, your `initTable` function should be:

```
void initTable()
{
    GtkWidget *button;
    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("button");
    table=gtk_table_new(4,4,true); //table created..
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table),button,0,1,0,1); //attaching frame container to table cell..

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),table,0,0,1);//attach menubar with vbox//

}
```

In order to compile we had to define `true`, `false` and `bool` (due to the includes, not sure of which framework you are using).

Full source code is:

```
 /* Button Boxes
 *
 * The Button Box widgets are used to arrange buttons with padding.
 */
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define true TRUE
#define false FALSE
#define bool gboolean

 GtkWidget *window,*button,*container,*menubar,*fileM,*menu,*vbox,*aboutM,*quitM,*bdrM;
 GtkWidget *image,*table,*Fileframe,*framecnt;
bool status=false;

void aboutDialog()
{
    GtkWidget *box;
    box=gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,GTK_BUTTONS_OK,"EXAMPLE");;
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(box));
    gtk_widget_destroy(box);

}

void Warning_quit()
{
    GtkWidget *box;
    box=gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,GTK_MESSAGE_WARNING,GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO,"Sure want to quit..");
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(box));
    gtk_widget_destroy(box);
    gtk_main_quit();

}

void toggle_Border()
{
    if(status==false)
    {
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window),true);
        gtk_menu_item_set_label(GTK_MENU_ITEM(bdrM),"fix");
        status=true;
    }
    else if(status==true)
    {
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window),false);
        gtk_menu_item_set_label(GTK_MENU_ITEM(bdrM),"move");
        status=false;

    }

}
void initDecoration()
{
    vbox=gtk_vbox_new(false,0);
    menubar=gtk_menu_bar_new();
    fileM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("file");
    aboutM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("about");
    quitM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("quit");
    bdrM=gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("move");
    menu=gtk_menu_new();
    ////////////////////////
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vbox);//attach vbox with window..
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar),fileM);//attach menu into menubar
    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(fileM),menu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu),aboutM);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar),bdrM);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu),quitM);//attach quit menu with menu..
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),menubar,0,0,1);//attach menubar with vbox//

    //attach signal intrrupt for menus..
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(aboutM),"activate",G_CALLBACK(aboutDialog),0);//signal for about menu..
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quitM),"activate",G_CALLBACK(Warning_quit),0);//signal for quit menu..
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(bdrM),"activate",G_CALLBACK(toggle_Border),0);
}

void initTable()
{
    GtkWidget *button;
    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("button");
    table=gtk_table_new(4,4,true); //table created..
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table),button,0,1,0,1); //attaching frame container to table cell..

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),table,0,0,1);//attach menubar with vbox//

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 200);
  //setup menubar;
  initDecoration();
  initTable();
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),"destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),0);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -o main main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .it works!!.but I don't understand that ,we can only create one child in a container ?and attaching to vbox didn't created new vbox element, then how it is attached to ?? vbox here is acting as reference or something else

Comment: No, that is not what i've said. Gtk.Window is a container that can only handle one child. Gtk.Box it's another kind of container which can hold **one or more, typically more** childs. These containers that only pack one child are simple containers while others like GtkBox, GtkGrid, GtkFixed, GtkLayout, GtkListBox, GtkFlowBox, etc... can pack more than one child. This is the normal "boxes-inside-boxes" model that Gtk uses (GtkFixed/GtkLayout use also the fixed position/sizing but that's another problem). So, when you added the GtkBox to the GtkWindow you already filled that container.

Comment: That's the reason why GtkWindow has a GtkBox, the GtkBox can pack many childs, including more GtkBoxes, vertical or horizontal. Another thing is that GtkBoxes are not created "on-the-fly", you create one and then packet other widgets in it and notice that widgets can't be packed in more that one container! Some GtkContainers, like GtkListBox can create, automatically, GtkListBoxRows but let's not get you confused.  What you have is a `GtkWindow > GtkBox > GMenu + GtkTable. Read your own code and try to understand it. Good luck!